# How do I pass in an argument to $mdDialog.cancel() when it's called from escapeToClose or clickOutsideToClose in AngularMaterial?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I'm using Angular Material `$mdDialog` service to open a dialog and show some content. What I'm trying to do is make an API call after that dialog has been closed with either `$mdDialog.cancel()` or `$mdDialog.hide()`. It needs to happen regardless of how the dialog was closed.

```
vm.preview = function($event) {
  $mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/dialog.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: $event,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    controller: PreviewController,
   })
   .then(sendRating)
   .catch(sendRating);
}
```

The function `sendRating` is just to DRY the code. It does an API call with already prepared data that I want to pass in through the `$mdDialog.hide() or $mdDialog.cancel()`.

To wrap up, the problem is the following:
I don't know how to pass in my data to the `$mdDialog.cancel()` method when the dialog is closed with Escape or by clickOutsideToClose.

Comment: Why not set `escapeToClose` and `clickOutsideToClose` as false to prevent unwanted closing of the md-dialog.

Comment: Across the app we have those set to true and it would be unexpected behaviour for the users.